# Force HTTPS and strip .HTML (Virtual Host .conf)

Tags: apache

I have been trying to set up a rewrite that will force https, remove www, and strip .html from any URLs. I'm spent approximately 2-3 hours trying to work it out but since I'm new to Apache servers, I've been having a bit of trouble...

Right now, my code below works to force https and remove www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.co.nz [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.co.nz
RewriteRule ^ https://example.co.nz%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

I have also tried adding the following code to strip the .html file extension, but it's does not working (I've also tested lots of other code from other StackOverflow answers without any use):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]
```

Any and all inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "It does not work" how?

Comment: I'm able to access all the /<name>.html files with /<name> but requesting example.co.nz will not work even though I have set the DirectoryIndex to index.html...